# Ansible nested variables in template

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I need to create playbook for provisioning multiple ethernet connections.

How to get mix of nested variables in a template from facts and user variables?

Exactly I need that for example:

```
{{ ansible_{{ net1 }}.macaddress }}
{{ ansible_{{ net2 }}.macaddress }}
```

Variables `net1`, `net2`, etc defined in `hosts_vars` that way:

```
net1: eth0
net2: br0
```

Is it possible at all? And if answer is yes, then how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There're several ways to do this.

You can use task vars or employ dictionary syntax to access the variable.

Here's a playbook demonstrating both methods:

```
- hosts: test.org
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: "{{ tmp_mac }}"
      vars:
        tmp_mac: ansible_{{net1}}.macaddress
    - debug:
        var: "hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_' + net1]['macaddress']"
```

Host variables file for `test.org`:

```
net1: enp3s0
```

Output:

```
ok: [test.org] => {
    "ansible_enp3s0.macaddress": "e8:b0:00:b5:bf:e2"
}
ok: [test.org] => {
    "hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_' + net1]['macaddress']": "e8:b0:00:b5:bf:e2"
}
```

Ansible uses Jinja2 templates, so searching for "Jinja2 variable nesting" may be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, Dmitry, that was very usefull.

Comment: how can this be done. ```region: 1 dev1_ips: 1,2  {{ dev[region]_ips }}```