# Issue with nested variables in YAML (ansible)

Tags: ansible, yaml

I'm facing an issue when playing with variables in YAML format

I'm trying **in the same task** to install packages for both x86_64 and s390x platform with ansible :

```
vars:
  x86_64_pckg:
    - p1
    - p2
    - p3
  s390x_pckg:
    - p4
    - p5
  
name: install backup tool
yum:
  name: "{{ {{ ansible_architecture }}_pckg }}"
  state: latest
```

I'm struggling with the quotes I think. But maybe my issue could only be resolved by creating two tasks and using the `when:` condition for managing the different architectures

Comment: [moustaches don't stack](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names)

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774205/ansible-nested-variables-in-template

Comment: As an overall best practice and as advised in [ask] you should use the above search box extensively before asking a question. You'll find several question with actual answers with the very same wording you used in your title.

Comment: I voted to close too. The solution is trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to work with nested variables you should use ansible.builtin.vars lookup.

So, if you change

`"{{ {{ ansible_architecture }}_pckg }}"`

to

`"{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.vars', ansible_architecture + '_pckg') }}"`

you'll be able to make a nested variable.

Documentation for more info: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/vars_lookup.html

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please refrain from answering questions on issues caused by obvious typos as they are [off topic](/help/off-topic). SO is not meant to replace existing documentations or tutorials and you should point users to those in a comment if you'd still like to help. You'll be able to comment anywhere once you reach 50 reputation points. You'll also be able to vote for closing such question as caused by a typo (or duplicate as there are already lots of question on the subject...) when you reach 250 reputation. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put the hashes into a dictionary. Then, the usage is trivial

```yaml
vars:

  pkg:
    x86_64: [p1, p2, p3]
    s390x: [p4, p5]

tasks:
  
  - yum:
      name: "{{ pkg[ansible_architecture }}"
      state: latest
```